# 23.10 Fresh install, USB peripherals lose power on sleep, can't wake from/keyboard mouse

Tags: usb, suspend

After a while my peripherals turn off and then I can't wake the thing back up. Didn't exhibit this behavior prior to installing 23.10

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.